# Neo4 cypher: Check if node with relationships to a list of node IDs exists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following node structure: `(:Patch)-[:INCLUDES]->(:Roster)-[:HAS]->(:PublicList)-[:INCLUDES]->(u:Unit)`

Then I have an array of `:Unit` ids: `[197, 196, 19, 20, 191, 171, 3, 174, 194, 185]`

I would like to check whether a `:PublicList` that has the `:INCLUDES` relationship to all the `:Unit` ids in the list already exists.

I tried writing a `COUNT` and `MATCH` query like this, but this just seems like an error-prone long-winded approach:

```
MATCH (p:Patch)-[:INCLUDES]->(r:Roster)-[:HAS]-(d:PublicList)
    WITH COLLECT(d) as drafts
    UNWIND drafts as draft
    WITH draft
    UNWIND [197, 196, 19, 20, 191, 171, 3, 174, 194, 185] as unitID
      MATCH (draft)-[:INCLUDES]->(u:Unit)
      WHERE id(u) = unitID
      WITH count(DISTINCT u) as draftUnits
    WITH COLLECT(draftUnits) as matchCounts
    RETURN matchCounts
```

Can someone help me write this so it returns a boolean if a `:PublicList` has a`:INCLUDES` relationship to all the IDs in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to first match the units, put them into a collection and then use the `ALL` predicate to check that the PublicList has a connection to all units.

```
MATCH (n:Unit) WHERE id(n) IN [197, 196, 19, 20, 191, 171, 3, 174, 194, 185]
WITH collect(n) AS units
MATCH (p:Patch)-[:INCLUDES]->(r:Roster)-[:HAS]-(d:PublicList)
WHERE ALL(x IN units WHERE (d)-[:INCLUDES]->(x))
RETURN count(*) AS matchCount
```

If you want to return the PublicList along with a boolean value if it matches all of them, you can slightly adjust like this

```
MATCH (n:Unit) WHERE id(n) IN [197, 196, 19, 20, 191, 171, 3, 174, 194, 185]
WITH collect(n) AS units
MATCH (p:Patch)-[:INCLUDES]->(r:Roster)-[:HAS]-(d:PublicList)
RETURN d, ALL(x IN units WHERE (d)-[:INCLUDES]->(x)) as matchAll
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, first time I see `ALL` in action :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good but can be improved. Just to fix it, you need to use

```
u.id = unitID
```

instead of

```
WHERE id(u) = unitID
```

The latter is an internal id function which is uses a unique identification to all other nodes in the same database while the latter is a simple property named: id